# turning (x1+x2)*y into a matrix, or calling function arguments from vectors with different length

Tags: r, matrix

I want to create a matrix which combines x arguments with y argument in function:

```
x1<-c(2, 4, 6)
x2<-c(1, 2, 3)
y<-c(0, 1, 10, 100, 1000)

f1<-function(x1, x2, y) {
  return((x1+x2)*y)
}
```

The result should be:

```
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
r1    0    3   30  300 3000
r2    0    6   60  600 6000
r3    0    9   90  900 9000
```

(Naming of the rows and columns is not important). It is likely one of the most basic things, but I am still running into a wall and wasn't able to google the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Look up your matrix rules.

```
as.matrix(x1+x2)%*%t(as.matrix(y))
```

Comment: I think you could remove the `as.matrix(` on 'y' as `t(y)` returns a matrix

Comment: or using built ins `tcrossprod(x1+x2, y)`

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the `y` and do the calculation

```
sapply(y,  function(u)  (x1 + x2) * u)
```

---

Or using the OP's function

```
sapply(y,  f1, x1 = x1, x2 = x2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    3   30  300 3000
[2,]    0    6   60  600 6000
[3,]    0    9   90  900 9000
```

Comment: Thank you, this might be also useful with different functions.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `outer` like below

```
> outer(x1 + x2, y)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    3   30  300 3000
[2,]    0    6   60  600 6000
[3,]    0    9   90  900 9000
```

Comment: @akrun haha, we came across to the same idea, cheers!